# Smart way to make divs the same size with css?

Tags: html, css

I have two different divs with various contents, and would like them to be the same height and width. It seems like a bad idea to set their height and width to a fixed pixel size, because their size should probably vary based on browser/screen size. Setting their width to a percentage works, but percentage is not an option for height.

Is there a way to ensure two divs have the same dimensions without setting to fixed pixel sizes? Or are fixed pixel sizes really so bad?

Comment: Are you saying percent for height is not an option in your specific case? Otherwise percent is definitely an option for height.

Comment: I believe height simply doesn't work with percentages. If I try to use it, my divs just size their height according to their contents.

Comment: It does work if the parent element has a specified height. Otherwise, what you described happens.

Comment: @ab11 have you thought about viewport units, `div{width:50vw;height:50vw;}`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0qaz7a70/ to demonstrate what lucasnadalutti said.

Comment: @sdcr height should be `50vh` not `50vw`

Comment: @zgood not in this case, OP wants it to be square if you read carefully.

Comment: @sdcr Opps, sorry I missed that

Comment: viewport sizes look pretty dangerous. my divs are part of a larger layout, viewport dimensions look like it might make my divs grow over other elements. probably tables are the best way to go?

Comment: @ab11 check out this if you have not seen it yet - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/css-maintain-div-aspect-ratio

Answer (score 3):

Having an outer div with `display: table;` and these two divs inside it with `display: table-cell;` should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest defining a container div which varies according to screen width (using `@media screen`) and using css3's flex to define your divs like so :

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="first-div">first div </div>
<div class="second-div">second div </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.first-div{
   -webkit-flex: 1; /* Safari 6.1+ */
   flex: 1;
    background-color:yellow;
   border: 2px solid black; 
}

.second-div{
    -webkit-flex: 1; /* Safari 6.1+ */
   flex: 1;
    background-color:blue;
     border: 2px solid black;  
}
.container{
    width:auto; 
    display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
    -webkit-align-items: center; /* Safari 7.0+ */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sujy3bq4/19/

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

When using height, you need to make sure that you have a full body to work with. By default, the `body` height is auto. If you set the height to `100%`, you can start to use the height attribute on child elements.

Just remember that height is always set to it's parent:

```css
body,html{height:100%;}
div{width:50%; height:50%;}
.el1{float:left; background:#f00;}
.el2{float:right; background:#0f0;}
```

```html
<div class="el1"></div>
<div class="el2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If using CSS3 is an option in your case then you can use the 'ViewPort Percentage Lengths" [Details on W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths).

Something like below should work. (Refer question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/make-div-100-height-of-browser-window) for more details.)

```
div {
    height:100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Super easy and intuitive way to make responsive, **square** containers
Scalable percentage heights with padding-bottom:

[See Codepen](http://codepen.io/heavilyedited/pen/PqpbPQ)

Basically, set the height to 0, and set the bottom padding to any percentage you'd like.

```css
.box {
  float: left;
  width: 23%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom:23%;
  margin: 1%;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="box">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    4
  </div>
</section>
```